# Symfony 3: Doctrine listAction: Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to make an easy listAction to retrieve data from Doctrine but I got this error:

```
Attempted to load class "ProductRepository" from namespace "AppBundle\Entity".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
```

This come out when i call the route ex.com/list that must
 to list the data coming from product table

**Controller:** (src/AppBundle/Controller)

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\MessageSelector;
use AppBundle\Entity\Product;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;


new Translator('it', new MessageSelector(), __DIR__.'/../cache');

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $request->getLocale();

    $request->setLocale('it');

    return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
        'base_dir' => realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/..'),
    ]);
}

/**
 *
 * @Route("list", name="list")
 * @return Response
 *
 */
public function listAction()
{
    return $product = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle\Entity\Product')
        ->findAll();

   /* if (!$product) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(
            'Nessun prodotto trovato'
        );
    }*/

}

/**
 * @Route("create",name="create")
 * @return Response
 */
public function createAction()
{
    $product = new Product();
    $product->setName('Pippo Pluto');
    $product->setPrice('19.99');
    $product->setDescription('Lorem ipsum dolor');
    $product->setSeller('1');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $em->persist($product);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->render('default/index.html.twig');
}

/**
 * @param $id
 * @Route("show/{id}",name="show/{id}")
 * @return Response
 */
public function showAction($id)
{
    $product = new Product();
    $product = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:Product')
        ->find($id);

    if (!$product) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(
            'Nessun prodotto trovato per l\'id '.$id
        );
    }
  }
}
```

**Entity:** (src/AppBundle/Entity)

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* Product
*
* @ORM\Table(name="product")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\ProductRepository")
*/
class Product
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="`id`", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="`name`", type="string")
 */
private $name;
/**
 * @var float
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="`price`", type="float")
 */
private $price;
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="`description`", type="string")
 */
private $description;
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="`seller`", type="integer")
 */
private $seller;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 *
 * @return Product
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}
/**
 * Set price
 *
 * @param float $price
 *
 * @return Product
 */
public function setPrice($price) {
    $this->price = $price;

    return $this;
}
/**
 * Set description
 *
 * @param string $description
 *
 * @return Product
 */
public function setDescription($description) {
    $this->description = $description;

    return $this;
}
/**
 * Set seller
 *
 * @param int $seller
 *
 * @return Product
 */
public function setSeller($seller) {
    $this->seller = $seller;

    return $this;
}
/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}
/**
 * Get price
 *
 * @return float
 */
public function getPrice()
{
    return $this->price;
}
/**
 * Get description
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getDescription()
{
    return $this->description;
}
/**
 * Get seller
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getSeller()
   {
    return $this->seller;
   }
}
```

I can't understand what I'm missing to use. thanks.

Comment: can you post the ProductRepository class code?

Comment: Try this command: `bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle`

Comment: @ciurciurek I think is working, ask me to return something in the controller, so I've used return $product but got "The controller must return a response (Array(0 => Object(AppBundle\Entity\Product), 1 => Object(AppBundle\Entity\Product), 2 => Object(AppBundle\Entity\Product), 3 => Object(AppBundle\Entity\Product), 4 => Object(AppBundle\Entity\Product)" what I must to return?

Comment: Can You show all controller class code? I think the problem is in your  annotation of listAction method.

Comment: I've just updated including all the controller

Comment: i might be wrong, but i think that is becouse You dont render anything. Try this code: `$product = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle\Entity\Product')
        ->findAll();  return $this->render('default/index.html.twig',['product' => $product]);`

Comment: I think you're right, now I haven't any error but can't see the result listed, Doctrine make the query right so I think now I can call the product object in twig

Comment: Yes,  You're right. Read [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html) for more information about templating.

Comment: thanks, please put as a reply so I can put as correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be wrong, but i think that is becouse You dont render anything. Try this code: `$product = $this->getDoctrine() ->getRepository('AppBundle\Entity\Product') ->findAll(); return $this->render('default/index.html.twig',['product' => $product]);`

Answer (score 1):

That error "Attempted to load class "ProductRepository" from namespace "AppBundle\Entity" is generated because you, by mistake I guess, renamed the `repositoryClass` in your `AppBundle/Entity/Product` class.

So instead of `* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\ProductRepository")` you should have `* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ProductRepository")`, which means that the repository classes are meant to be located into `Repository` directory and not `Entity`.

And a controller action method must always return a response, or a redirect, etc.

And, even though your way works too, you would always want to call the `findAll()` method on a repository object, and not an entity one. So, again,
in your `listAction` instead of `->getRepository('AppBundle\Entity\Product')->findAll()` needs to be `->getRepository('AppBundle:Product')->findAll()`